# Parameter error_page doesn't work at all

Tags: solspace-freeform, error

I have a simple form calling it with `{exp:freeform:form}` composer tags.
Inside of it I put the `error_page` parameter but it still renders the default error page. I am really stuck in this situation and I can't get over it.

Here's part of my code :

```
{exp:freeform:form 
    form_id="2" 
    required="full_name|email|phone_number|comment" 
    return="/thank-you/"
    error_page="/en/error/"
}

...

{/exp:freeform:form}
```

I am using Freeform Pro 4.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your error page is an actual template. Also I believe you have to have freeform pro to use this feature ( http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/error_page/ )

Comment: I have also seen issues in the past when the error template did not have the error page tags in it.